# How to create a variable in env.rb or hook.rb and call in cucumber feature ?

Tags: ruby, testing, cucumber

Thank you in advance for help.

I am trying to create variable in env.rb

```
File_path =("#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/../../features/TestData/Testdata.html")
```

and call File_path in the Cucumber feature directly.

```
for example
...
And I upload a file from path "<File_path>"
...
```

Is the is a better way of doing this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there's a better way.

In your feature text, use meaningful names instead of file paths.

For example, any of these, depending on your goal:

```
And I upload a file of test data 

And I upload my web page

And I upload some previously saved information
```

Then put the file path in your step file.

In general, feature descriptions should be plain language, not source code, file paths, env vars, etc